# proving of inequality $(n!)^2 \leq n^n\cdot n!\leq (2n!)$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics

How can we prove the inequality $(n!)^2 \leq n^n\cdot n!\leq (2n!)$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$\bf{My \; Try}$::

$1\leq n$

$2\leq n$

$3\leq n$

....

....

$n\leq n$

So $1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 ..n \leq n^n$

So $n!\leq n^n\Rightarrow (n!)^2 \leq n^n\cdot n!$

But  did not understand how can we prove $n^n\cdot n! \leq (2n!)$

Help me

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean $(2n)!$, not $2n!$. It's easier then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2n)!=2n\cdot(2n-1)\cdot...\cdot(n+1)\cdot n!$$,

so $n\le 2n$, $n \le 2n-1$,...