# proving an inequality for all natural numbers

Tags: inequality, induction, natural-numbers

My textbook mentions a problem which is as follows:

Prove the inequalities $ (n!)^2 \le n^n\cdot n! \lt (2n)! $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
It also has a solution but in a intuitive way. I am thinking to prove it by mathematical induction.

Let $P(n) : (n!)^2 \le n^n \cdot n! \lt (2n)!$

$\mathbf{Base \ Case}$:

$P(1): (1!)^2 \le 1^1 \cdot 1!\lt (2\cdot1)! \implies 1 \le 1\lt 2$

Hence, $P(1)$ is true

$\mathbf{Induction \ Hypothesis}$:

Suppose $P(m)$ is true for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$\implies (m!)^2 \le m^m \cdot m! \lt (2m)!$$

Now, $$((m+1)!)^2 = (m+1)! \cdot(m+1)! = m! \cdot (m+1)(m+1)!  \le m^{m*} \cdot (m+1) \cdot (m+1)! \le (m+1)^{m**} (m+1)(m+1)!$$

$$\implies ((m+1)!)^2 \le (m+1)^{m+1}(m+1)!$$

$*$ Using induction hypothesis

$** m \le m+1 \implies m^m \le (m+1) ^m$

But for the second inequality , I am stuck. Please someone help.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proving of inequality $(n!)^2 \leq n^n\cdot n!\leq (2n!)$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564983/proving-of-inequality-n2-leq-nn-cdot-n-leq-2n-where-n-in-mathbbn) . Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(n!)%5E2%20%5Cle%20n%5En%5Ccdot%20n!%20%5Clt%20(2n)!%24&p=2). Also, FYI, there's the closely related [How and why does one come up with inequalities such as $(n!)^2\leq n^n(n!)<(2n)!\;$?](/q/3925934) that you may find interesting.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes that's the same solution my book gives but i want to prove this using induction.

Comment: OK, I retracted my close vote. However, I'm leaving the duplicate request comment for anybody who comes across this post so they can see how else to solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that $n^n \times n! \times (\sqrt{2})^{n}\le (2n)! $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821706/how-to-prove-that-nn-times-n-times-sqrt2n-le-2n) - the proofs are by induction.

Comment: $n!^2\leq n^n~n!$ would imply that $n!\leq n^n$ which is not true, consider $n=2$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to prove an equality $$a(n) \leq b(n) \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
by induction it is *sufficient* (but not necessary) that the base case is indeed true and then
$$\frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)} \leq \frac{b(n+1)}{b(n)} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
The same argument works for strict inequality.

This drastically simplifies your problem: you now only need to show that
$$\left(m+1\right)^2 \leq \frac{(m+1)^{m+1}}{m^m} \cdot (m+1) < (2m + 1)(2m+2) \quad \forall m \in \mathbb{N}.$$

The first inequality is equivalent to
$$m+1 \leq \left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)^m \cdot (m + 1),$$
which is obviously true.
The second one is equivalent to
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)^m \cdot (m + 1) < 2(2m + 1)$$
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)^m < 4 - \frac{2}{m+1},$$
which is a little bit more tricky. Using the binomial theorem we can write
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)^m = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n\cdot ... \cdot (n-k+1)}{n^k \cdot k!} < 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!} < 1 + \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} < 1 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} = 1 + 2 = 3.$$
So we can use this to prove the above inequality whenever $\frac{2}{m+1} < 1$, i.e. $m > 2$. And for $m=1, 2$ you can check it by hand.

P.S. The last paragraph is basically the standart proof that number $e = \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)^m$ is less than $3$. If you also know the fact that $\left(1 + \frac{1}{m}\right)^m$ is monotonously increasing then there's nothing left to show then :) However this is also proved via basically the same argument.